# Setting environment variable for a running program in linux

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, signals

My program uses an environment variable `DBG_MSG` value to determine the level of debug messages. `DBG_MSG=3` prints the maximum debug information.

However whenever the program is behaving in a strange unexpected way the environment variable is not set to print the full debug information. And when program is rerun with environment set it won't show the same error.

I am thinking of implementing a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` to set this environment variable at runtime, using `putenv(3)`. This way I can send the signal to a hung job to make it print more debug info.

What are some safety measures to take when doing this ?

Are there any other ways to change environment of a running program from outside ?

Comment: I'm confused. Probably others will be as well.

Comment: The problem is that the bug disappears when you print debug messages, which means your program invokes undefined behavior, so a debugger will help a lot, a memory debugger like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) will even help more, and posting the problematic code will be of help to the person who might help you.

Comment: @iharob What you say is true except that this is much more likely to be a race condition leading to deadlock than a memory corruption problem (so, `helgrind` instead of `valgrind` maybe) and the description makes me think we're talking about a very large, complicated network daemon that would not be practical to post even a cut-down version of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`putenv` is not [async-signal-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837343/difference-between-thread-safe-and-async-signal-safe), and therefore should **never** be called from a `SIGUSR1` handler.  Also, changes made by `putenv` are not necessarily noticed by `getenv` calls in another thread.

What you should do instead is read your `DBG_MSG` environment variable only once, on startup, and store the value in a global variable with type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.  Your debug-logging routines should look at this variable to decide how much information to print.  Then you have your signal handler adjust the value of the variable.

I would suggest, also, that `SIGUSR1` should increment the variable, and `SIGUSR2` should *decrement* it.  That way you can both raise and lower the log level, as necessary.

`sig_atomic_t` may be very small, and is not guaranteed to be either signed or unsigned: a portable program can only use it to store values in the range 0 through 127 inclusive.  Therefore, make sure that your signal handlers clamp the value to the range that is meaningful for your program (that is, don't increment the log level past the maximum or reduce it past the minimum).

Answer (score 1):

The safety measures are: don't do it.

`putenv(3)` is not async-signal safe (mostly because it can call `malloc(3)`), and so you shouldn't really call it from a signal handler.

Comment: It's not safe to call arbitrary functions from `gdb` either; in fact, depending on where you broke into the program it could be *exactly* as risky as calling them from an async signal handler.

Comment: @zwol Oh, I had no idea. That's interesting. Thanks for letting me know! I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: I am aware of this hack and have used it in development. But I am looking for a more user friendly way to do this. Something that a user can activate if needed.

Comment: Think about it this way: Async signal handlers have to be very careful what they do because they could have interrupted execution of any part of the program (unless signals are blocked), including the guts of a library function. Well, a debugger break-in is *even more* invasive than that: it can even interrupt a program that has all blockable signals blocked.  So it is necessary to be even more cautious when calling back into the program. (The human driving the debugger can inspect the call stack and decide what's safe to do, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are not mettling with env variable from within your program. Env variables should be set once from your shell and leave alone. .. after all , they are environment variables . They just setup or define an environment for your program.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way ....
you can implement ioctl calls also ..

even many drivers are doing same thing ..

Comment: Could you elaborate ?